# How to transform a metric distance into a distance in degree using GeodeticCalculator from JTS?

Tags: geotools, jts

I need to transform a distance of 50m into a distance in degree. The Azimuth is given as 45° and we have to do that using org.geotools.referencing.GeodeticCalculator (http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/GeodeticCalculator.html).

Unfortunatly the other students and me have no idea how to fix that.

Thanks in advance for help guys!
Lukas

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you don't want to do that, what you really want is to calculate the point that is 50m away in a specified direction from another point. To do that you simply set the start point, distance and direction in the calculator.

```
    DefaultGeographicCRS crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
    GeodeticCalculator calc = new GeodeticCalculator(crs);
    GeometryFactory geomFactory = new GeometryFactory();
    Point point = geomFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(0.0, 50.0));

    calc.setStartingGeographicPoint(point.getX(), point.getY());
    // azimuth in degrees -180 - 180
    double azimuth = 90.0;
    // distance in metres
    double distance = 50;
    calc.setDirection(azimuth, distance);
    Point2D p = calc.getDestinationGeographicPoint();

    System.out.println(p);
```

Comment: Hey Ian,

well, the the context of the questien ist that we have OSM-datas and we should simplify the geometry of the features with com.vividsolutions.jts.simplify.TopologyPreservingSimplifier. But for the TopologyPreservingSimplifier we need a distance that is given individually by the user in meter and has to be transformed. And for this transformation we have to use the GeodeticCalculator. I dont know if that makes sense at all :D

Comment: That would be a bad idea, convert the data into a local projection and use the distance given in metres on that and project back. Don't use JTS in geographic coordinate systems.