# Need a way in JTS library to find new Lat Long coordinates at X length in given angle from starting lat long

Tags: java, scala, geotools, jts

I am trying my hands on locationtech JTS library. I wanted to find any built methods from JTS that can help me get a new coordinate given that I have following data with me:

1. Originating Point
2. Distance to the new coordinate
3. Bearing angle direction for finding the new coordinate

Also are there any resources apart from Javadocs of JTS library for easier comprehension?

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70952611/439194) should do it for you

Answer (score 0):

To do that you simply set the start point, distance and direction in the `GeodeticCalculator`.

```
DefaultGeographicCRS crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
GeodeticCalculator calc = new GeodeticCalculator(crs);
GeometryFactory geomFactory = new GeometryFactory();
Point point = geomFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(0.0, 50.0));

calc.setStartingGeographicPoint(point.getX(), point.getY());
// azimuth in degrees -180 - 180
double azimuth = 90.0;
// distance in metres
double distance = 50;
calc.setDirection(azimuth, distance);
Point2D p = calc.getDestinationGeographicPoint();

System.out.println(p);
```